How do I import a non-typed Leaflet plugin into an Angular project?
I am looking to import the leaflet plugin leaflet-mapwithlabels into my angular project. The library has no option for NPM installation and following some guides, I tried adding the JS file directly to the node-modules in its own folder and then importing it as such in my component:
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import {GeoJSON} from "leaflet";
import "node_modules/leaflet-mapwithlabels/dist/leaflet-mapwithlabels.js"

and adding it into my angular.json:
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/azure-blue.css",
              "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "./node_modules/leaflet-mapwithlabels/dist/leaflet-mapwithlabels.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
              "./node_modules/leaflet-mapwithlabels/dist/leaflet-mapwithlabels.js"
            ]

and calling it here:
  private map!: L.MapWithLabels;

but that didn't work. So how can i go about adding it.
Relevant info:
package.json:
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.12",
    ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@bluehalo/ngx-leaflet": "^18.0.2",
    "@ngageoint/geopackage": "^4.2.6",
    "@stijn98s/leaflet.tilelayer.pouchdbcached": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/leaflet.fullscreen": "^3.0.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet-geometryutil": "^0.10.3",
    "leaflet.fullscreen": "^3.0.2",

Update: this is what I am trying now, it still doesn't work, but I got a different error:
I moved the JS file and added this to my angular.json:
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
  "./node_modules/leaflet.fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.js",
  "./src/assets/scripts/leaflet-mapwithlabels.js"
]

I created a leaflet-extensions.d.ts in my src/types folder:
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as geojson from "geojson";
import {Layer} from "leaflet";

declare module 'leaflet' {
  interface LayerOptions {
    label?: string | ((layer: L.Layer) => string);
    labelPriority?: number | ((layer: L.Layer) => number);
    labelGap?: number;
    labelPos?: 'auto' | 'r' | 'l' | 'cc';
    labelStyle?: { [key: string]: string };
    labelRepeatAlongLines?: boolean;
    labelRepeatDistance?: number;
  }
  export class MapWithLabels extends
    Map
  {
    constructor(element: string | HTMLElement, options?: MapWithLabelsOptions);
  }
  export interface MapWithLabelsOptions extends MapOptions {
    labelPane?: string;
  }
  export function mapWithLabels(element: string | HTMLElement, options?: MapWithLabelsOptions): MapWithLabels;
  type TypeOrFn<T, Ly extends Layer> = T | ((layer: Ly) => T)
  interface LabelFns<Ly extends Layer> {
    label?: TypeOrFn<string, Ly>;
    labelStyle?: TypeOrFn<object, Ly>;
    labelPriority?: TypeOrFn<number, Ly>;
  }
  export interface LayerOptions extends LabelFns<LayerWithFeature> {
    labelPos?: string;
    // etc.
  }
  class LayerWithFeature<P = any, G extends geojson.GeometryObject = geojson.GeometryObject> extends Layer {
    feature?: geojson.Feature<G, P>
  }
  export interface GeoJSONOptions<P = any, G extends geojson.GeometryObject = geojson.GeometryObject>
    extends LabelFns<LayerWithFeature<P, G>> { }
}

declare module "leaflet-map-with-labels" {
  export = L;
}

and I'm using it like this:
import { 
Injectable 
} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { Geometry } from 'geojson';
import { CountryProperties } from "../model/interfaces";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MapService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  initMap(elementId: string): L.MapWithLabels {
    return L.mapWithLabels(elementId, {
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 10,
      zoomControl: true,
      attributionControl: false,
      inertia: true,
      inertiaDeceleration: 3000,
      inertiaMaxSpeed: 1500,
      easeLinearity: 0.1,
      zoomSnap: 0.5,
      preferCanvas: false
    })
  }
  loadGeoJSON(url: string): Observable<GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<Geometry, CountryProperties>> {
    return this.http.get<GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<Geometry, CountryProperties>>(url);
  }
}

but I'm still getting an error:
ERROR TypeError: L.mapWithLabels is not a function
at _MapService.initMap (map.service.ts:16:14)

So if anyone knows what i'm doing wrong and can help, it would be highly appreciated.

Once you have added the JavaScript file into angular.json > "scripts" array, then you are left with adding the missing TypeScript definitions for the new classes, factories and options introduced by the library.
In this case, you could do something like:
import * as geojson from 'geojson';
import { Layer } from 'leaflet';

declare module "leaflet" {
    export class MapWithLabels extends Map {
        constructor(element: string | HTMLElement, options?: MapWithLabelsOptions);
    }
    export interface MapWithLabelsOptions extends MapOptions {
        labelPane?: string;
    }
    export function mapWithLabels(element: string | HTMLElement, options?: MapWithLabelsOptions): MapWithLabels;

    type TypeOrFn<T, Ly extends Layer> = T | ((layer: Ly) => T)
    interface LabelFns<Ly extends Layer> {
        label?: TypeOrFn<string, Ly>;
        labelStyle?: TypeOrFn<object, Ly>;
        labelPriority?: TypeOrFn<number, Ly>;
    }

    export interface LayerOptions extends LabelFns<LayerWithFeature> {
        labelPos?: string;
        // etc.
    }

    class LayerWithFeature<P = any, G extends geojson.GeometryObject = geojson.GeometryObject> extends Layer {
        feature?: geojson.Feature<G, P>
    }
}

Then TypeScript lets you use these additional classes, factories and options:
import L from "leaflet";
import './assets/scripts/leaflet-mapwithlabels';

class MyComponent {
    private map!: L.MapWithLabels;
}

// Samples from library docs
const map = L.mapWithLabels('map_div', { labelPane: "tooltipPane" });

// fetch geojson data and create a polygon layer with labels
fetch('hu_megyek.geojson').then(r => r.json()).then(d => {
    L.geoJSON(d, {
        label: l => l.feature?.properties.Nev,
        labelPos: 'cc',
        labelStyle: { color: 'darkblue', whiteSpace: 'normal', minWidth: '120px', textAlign: 'center' },
        labelPriority: l => l.feature?.properties.Nepesseg,
    }).addTo(map);
});

Playground Link
Note: in order for leaflet-mapwithlabels plugin to extend the same L global object as what you try using in your application, make sure to then import Leaflet L exported object directly, instead of "rebuilding" the namespace with "import * as L":
import L from 'leaflet'; // Import "L" directly, instead of "* as L"

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tyrpr2?file=src%2FMapService.service.ts

Thank you for the answer,I added this in the @types folder in its own leaflet-mapswithlabels folder as index.d.ts.
In my angular.json:
"src/assets/scripts/leaflet-mapwithlabels.js"
In the component:
import * as L from 'leaflet'; import 'leaflet.fullscreen'; ...   private map!: L.MapWithLabels; ...     L.mapWithLabels('something', {labelPane: "something"});
I got the error:
X [ERROR] TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/hadin/WebstormProjects/mapadaypoc/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index"' has no exported member 'MapWithLabels'. 

See updated answer. In your question edit, please make sure to explain that part of your new code comes from this answer, otherwise it confuses what comes from where.
